# lua indexing a nil value

Tags: indexing, lua, null

I have been googling this issue to no avail so far so I was wondering if anyone might know the answer - when you index a nil value in lua, the script raises an error - attemp to index 'variableName' - a nil value - is it possible to instead capture that with may be a metamethod, do some processing and not error out? For example if variable 'num' is not defined and you say 'num = 2' you can set the __newindex metamethod to do some processing and you have both the variable name - 'num' and the value - '2' on the stack, but if you say 'num[2] = 3' and 'num' is not defined you error out - instead just like __newindex, I want to capture that event and get access to the name of the nil variable - 'num', the index - 2, and the set value - 3. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the question isn't totally clear. are you saying num is a table variable? or num is just a local variable to the script?

Comment: it is neither , 'num' has not yet been defined at all - but you try to index it anyways and instead of raising an error i want the undefined variable name - 'num', the index and the value so i can do some processing, just like using __newindex

Answer (score 1):

you can override the __newindex metamethod on the global table.

```
function OnNewIndex(tbl, key, value)
    if tbl[key] == nil then
        print(tostring(key).. " doesn't exist.")
    end
end

setmetatable(_G, { __newindex = OnNewIndex })

num = 15
```

however, by default I don't believe lua has this behavior. just doing something like:

```
num = 15
```

should just declare the variable 'num' as a global and assign the value 15 to it. are you using lua as part of some framework that has strict checking for this?

edit: an easy way to 'catch' this error without letting it bubble to the surface would be to wrap the assignment in a pcall like this...

```
pcall(function() num[2] = 15 end)
```

if you print this, you'll get the output:

```
false   test2.lua:18: attempt to index global 'num' (a nil value)
```

which at least gives you some indication of what happened, if you named the function, i guess you could potentially try to recover.

```
function TrySetValue()
    num[2] = 15
end

local result, msg = pcall(TrySetValue)
if (not result) then
    num = {}
end

result, msg = pcall(TrySetValue)
print(result, msg)
print(num[2])
```

seems like an awful lot of work when you could probably just fix the code up front.

Comment: I guess i am not clear enough: if i override the __newindex metamethod statements like : num = 15 , where num is an undeclared variable will get caught and you can do something with both the string 'num' and the value 15. But a statement like: num[2] = 15 , where num is undeclared will cause an error regardless whether we have overwritten __newindex. The error is: 'attempt to index 'num' - a nil value'

Comment: yeah, i don't think there is really a way for you to 'catch' what you're trying to catch without wrapping the assignment in a pcall() and trying to recover from the error. think about what you're doing. you're trying to catch an __index for the _G table, create a new table, catch that __index, and assign the value for THAT. i'm not really sure how you'd do that, when really you should be explicitly creating num first before trying to index it. that's pretty standard programming principle.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's easier to help if you state the problem you're trying to solve. Are you trying to prevent uninitialized globals from being used? You can do that with a metatable. Are you trying to make sure script errors never percolate up to your app? You can do that with `pcall`. Are you really only trying to catch this one specific usage of a `nil` global, and recover from it in some way? The more context you give, the easier it is for others to find a solution you might not have thought of.

As for the situation you described, where you want to catch `num[index]` where `num` is `nil`, you can't really detect that directly.

There are two parts to this:

1. when the current value of `num` is read from the current environment table (aka _ENV or _G)
2. when you attempt to index that value.

There's no way you can detect #2, because `nil` is not a table so you can't give it a metatable.

However, you *can* detect #1. Depending on your requirements you *could* use #1 to return a proxy object which will then allow you to detect #2, however this will mean no global will ever be `nil`, so logic like this won't work:

```
--- initialize globalFoo if it doesn't exists
if not globalFoo then
    globalFoo = CreateGlobalFoo()
    ....
```

Of course you could always do something like name your proxy object `NIL`, so you could write:

```
if globalFoo == NIL then -- globalFoo is not initilalize
    globalFoo = CreateGlobalFoo()
```

Example of a proxy object that works like that:

```
local nil_proxy_mt = {
    __index    = function(t,k)   print('Attempted to index nil!') end,
    __newindex = function(t,k,v) print('Attempted to index nil!') end,
}

local NIL = setmetatable({}, nil_proxy_mt)

setmetatable (_G, { __index = function(t,k) return NIL end })
```

With this in place, if you tried either of these:

```
foo = num[2]
num[2] = 15
```

You'll get "Attempted to index nil!" and the program continues running.

Comment: I will give this a go when i come back on Monday and post back any additional comments.